# How to expose additional models : Migrating from Springfox to Springdoc

Tags: openapi, springdoc

I need to expose some models which don't used directly in REST API methods.

With springfox I used Docket's `additionalModels` method to programmatically add models to specification:

```
docket.additionalModels(
  typeResolver.resolve(XModel1.class),
  typeResolver.resolve(XModel2.class)
)
```

How to do it with springdoc?

I've created a dummy operation with dummy-parameter which includes all required models. But I feel the approach has space for improvement.

Comment: It's hard to understand what is your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

With OpenApiCustomiser , you have access to the OpenAPI Object.
You can add any object/operation you want without having to add annotations on your code.

You can have a look at the documentation for more details:

- https://springdoc.org/#how-can-i-customise-the-openapi-object

Comment: Thanks. I've created customizer, with `openApi.components.schemas.putAll(ModelConverters.getInstance().read(Foo::class.java))`, but no Foo model in generated spec found. I think it is swagger issue, not springdoc

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin

```
fun components(): Components {
    val components = Components()

    val converter = ModelConverters.getInstance()

    val schema1 = converter.readAllAsResolvedSchema(XModel1::class.java)
    val schema2 = converter.readAllAsResolvedSchema(XModel2::class.java)

    schema1.referencedSchemas.forEach { s -> components.addSchemas(s.key, s.value) }
    schema2.referencedSchemas.forEach { s -> components.addSchemas(s.key, s.value) }

    return components
}
```

Additionally you may need to specify the property in *application.yml*:

> ```
> springdoc:
>     remove-broken-reference-definitions: false
> ```