# Default response class in springdoc

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to add a default error model to all endpoints in my API, for some error codes.

I found a partial solution by reading the following issues:

- [Springfox -> Springdoc: How to expose additional models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302708/springfox-springdoc-how-to-expose-additional-models)
- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/381

This is the bean I am creating for that customisation:

```
    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser customOpenApiCustomiser() {
        return openApi -> {
            openApi.getPaths().values().forEach(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().forEach(operation -> {

                Schema sharedErrorSchema = ModelConverters.getInstance()
                        .read(Error.class)
                        .getOrDefault("Error", new Schema());

                MediaType sharedMediaType = new MediaType().schema(sharedErrorSchema);
                Content sharedContent = new Content()
                        .addMediaType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, sharedMediaType);

                ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();

                ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse()
                        .description("Unhandled server error")
                        .content(sharedContent);
                apiResponses.addApiResponse("500", response);
            }));
        };
    }
```

And my Error class looks something like:

```
public class Error {
    private String message;
    private List<ErrorItem> errorItems;
}
```

The problem is that when I open one of the endpoints definition in swagger-ui, I am getting the following error:

`Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/ErrorItem does not exist in document`

How can I define the schema for ErrorItem, making it available for swagger-ui?

I am using:

- Spring Boot => 2.2.4.Release
- springdoc-openapi-ui => 1.3.0
- springdoc-openapi-security => 1.3.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similiar issue and resolved it today:

First you have to add all java-types to the components:

```
// add Error and ErrorItem to schema
openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().putAll(ModelConverters.getInstance().read(Error.class));
openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().putAll(ModelConverters.getInstance().read(ErrorItem.class));
```

Then you have to create a Schema-Ref to use it in your response:

```
// add default responses
// Ref to Error-Object (added in step above)
Schema errorResponseSchema = new Schema();
errorResponseSchema.setName("Error");
errorResponseSchema.set$ref("#/components/schemas/Error");
```

Now you can use this ref. In this example i use Error only for BadRequest, all other default responses don't use a schema. Change it as you need it :-)

```
openApi.getPaths().values().forEach(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().forEach(operation -> {
  ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();
  apiResponses.addApiResponse("400", createApiResponse("BadRequest", errorResponseSchema));
  apiResponses.addApiResponse("403", createApiResponse("Forbidden", null));
  apiResponses.addApiResponse("404", createApiResponse("Not Found", null));
  apiResponses.addApiResponse("500", createApiResponse("Server Error", null));
}));
```

Where createApiResponse is just a simple private function:

```
private ApiResponse createApiResponse(String message, Schema schema) {
  MediaType mediaType = new MediaType();
  mediaType.schema(schema);
  return new ApiResponse().description(message)
                .content(new Content().addMediaType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, mediaType));
}
```

Make sure you get the right import for your Error.class, per default it will be java.lang.Error.

Comment: While creating openApi bean, paths will be null. What is the hook you are using for customizing paths on openApi object i.e., to execute 
 openApi.getPaths().values().forEach(pathItem -> {}),

Comment: This is an awesome post. Very helpful.Thank you!

Comment: Is there something like ModelConverters for reading the Parameters model from a method?

Comment: Better than manually registering all classes, do this (Kotlin): ModelConverters.getInstance().readAllAsResolvedSchema(RootErrorClass::class.java).referencedSchemas.forEach { (k, v) -> openApi.components.addSchemas(k, v) }

This will automatically resolve all unknown complex types.

Comment: @PavanKumar use a `OpenApiCustomizer` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "prettier" version of all this.

SpringDoc provides their own static method set to automatically add unresolved schemas to the components (and OpenAPI object respectively), so they can be referenced from other places.

```java
import io.swagger.v3.core.util.AnnotationsUtils;

@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser errorCustomizer() {
    return api -> api.getPaths().values().forEach(path -> path.readOperations()
        .forEach(operation -> addErrorToApi(operation, api.getComponents())));
}

private void addErrorToApi(Operation operation, Components components) {
    MediaType mediaType = new MediaType().schema(AnnotationsUtils.resolveSchemaFromType(Error.class, components, null));
    operation.getResponses().addApiResponse("500", new ApiResponse()
        .description("Unhandled Server Error")
        .content(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, mediaType);
}
```

Tested with Java 8 + Spring Boot 2.7.18 + SpringDoc UI 1.8.0, no problems so far.

NOTE: `AnnotationsUtils.resolveSchemaFromType()` returns REFERENCED schema, not the original one. That means that it won't have provided examples in fields, etc. To override examples, you need to access `Components` object and extract schema by your schema name (annotated classes' simple name by default):

```java
components.getSchemas().get(Error.class.getSimpleName());
```

EDIT: it also introspects and adds all child schemas, so by calling one `resolveSchemaFromType()` you will have all schemas correctly added and referenced in your API components. Here is an example of my class that I had problem with adding by calling plain `ModelConverters` method:

```java
@Schema
@Getter
@Setter // lombok annotations
public class Error {

    private List<NestedError> nestedErrors;

    @Schema
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class NestedError {

        private ErrorField;
        private String reason;
    }

    @Schema
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class ErrorField {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When calling `MediaConverters` manually, I had to register child schemas in addition to the `Error` schema.